# Does Google Publisher Tag have a slot render fail event?

Tags: javascript, google-ad-manager

In success case, they have an event

```js
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {
  console.log('Slot has been rendered:');
  console.log(event);
});
```

but how to know if slot render has failed?

Comment: what do you mean by fail ? When no ad is returned  (is empty) ?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know if empty, or no Ad item. 
If then, i will add other component instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider an empty adslot = failed adcall:

As detailed in the [GPT Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent_isEmpty), the SlotRenderEnded is able to tell you if isEmpty = true, which means the adcall returned nothing.

To do so, you can use for instance :

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function (event) {
  if(event.isEmpty) {
     //whatever you need to do if the adcall ended empty
  }
  else {
     //what to do if the adcall is not empty
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I want :)